# Add Pagination in HTML Table Data Load by Axios Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have loaded Data in HTML table from javascript getting HTTP response using 
Axios. Here is my code where I load data from JSON response using axios.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
axios.get(allChannel_api, common).then(function (result) {
    var resultjson = JSON.stringify(result.data.resultSet);
    table = document.getElementById('tblallchannel');
    var newTableData = "";
    var fa_fa_trash = "fa fa-trash";
    var tsttrue = "true";
    var style = "color: red";


    for (let i = 0; i < result.data.resultSet.length; i++) {

        let tableItem = "<tr><td>" + result.data.resultSet[i].channelName + "</td>";
        tableItem = tableItem + '<td style = "display:none;">' + result.data.resultSet[i].id + '</td>';
        tableItem = tableItem + '<td><label class="switch"><span class="slider round"></span></label></td>';
        tableItem = tableItem + '<td><a href="#" onClick="onDelete(' + result.data.resultSet[i].id + ')" ><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red"></i></a></td></tr>';
        newTableData += tableItem;

    }
    $('#tblallchannel').html(newTableData);

});
```

I want to add pagination based on my total data by this result.data.resultSet.length . I have length how can I add pagination .

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to do pagination client-side or server-side? Depending on the amount of data, it may make more sense to do it server-side.

If its client side though..based on the code above, You could approach it a couple of different ways.

2 things you need are the limit per page (e.x. 10 results per page), and current page being viewed.

below is 1 way to do it, just create an array of all the pages, then you can grab content for the page number by calling getContent() and passing in the page number.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
axios.get(allChannel_api, common).then(function (result) {
    var resultjson = JSON.stringify(result.data.resultSet);
    table = document.getElementById('tblallchannel');
    var newTableData = "";
    var fa_fa_trash = "fa fa-trash";
    var tsttrue = "true";
    var style = "color: red";

    var limit = 10;
        var page = 1;

        // put content in array of arrays
        var results = [[]];

        var count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < result.data.resultSet.length; i++) {
        count++

        // if we hit page limit, create new page and start count from 0 again
        if (count === limit) {
            count = 0;
            results.push([]); // create new page
        }

      let tableItem = "<tr><td>" + result.data.resultSet[i].channelName + "</td>";
      tableItem = tableItem + '<td style = "display:none;">' + result.data.resultSet[i].id + '</td>';
      tableItem = tableItem + '<td><label class="switch"><span class="slider round"></span></label></td>';
      tableItem = tableItem + '<td><a href="#" onClick="onDelete(' + result.data.resultSet[i].id + ')" ><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red"></i></a></td></tr>';

      // grab latest page and push the item into the page
      results[results.length - 1].push(tableItem)
    }

    // return content for the requested page
    function getContent (p) {
        if (p > totalPages) {
            return ''; // empty or something
        }
        return results[p - 1].join(''); // joining the array of strings into 1 string
    }

    var totalPages = results.length;

    $('#tblallchannel').html(getContent(page));

});
```

Comment: It will be client as there is not more than 50 rows

Answer (score 0):

In order to add pagination in your page you can use [Data Table](https://datatables.net/) plugin it's a great plugin and easy to use.